# Can I make synchronous call with `request` npm package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, request

I am using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module in my NodeJS application, for making server-to-server API calls. I am making the API call like this:

```
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if( error ){
       // return error response
    }
    // return success response here
});
```

For some reason, I need to **not use** this asynchronous way of making call, but do it synchronously. So, is there any way to make this call in synchronous manner. I tried and found some other modules for this, but I need to use this same module.

Thanks

Comment: *For some reason, I need to not use this asynchronous way of making call, but do it synchronously.* - consider providing the reason and explaining your case. There's a good chance you have XY problem that should be solved in another way. There's https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-request . It's a hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because an HTTP request is asynchronous by nature, you cannot do it synchronously. However, you can use ES6+ `Promises` and `async/await` like so:

```
// First, encapsulate into a Promise
const doRequest = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if( error ){
    reject(error)
  }
  resolve(response)
});

// And then, use async/await

const x = 1 + 1

const response = await myRequest()

console.log(response)
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot not. Request will return you promise and you have to handle it somewhere using .then() or calling the function with async/await pattern.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by @Errorname, promises are probably what you are looking for. Instead of writing the code by hand, you could also use the package `request-promise`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise

Answer (score 1):

If you want a strongly-typed, synchronous client, you can try out **ts-sync-request**.

NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-sync-request

This library is a wrapper around sync-request.

You can attach a header & make a request like below:

```
import { SyncRequestClient } from 'ts-sync-request/dist'
```

```
let url = "http://someurl.com";

let response = new SyncRequestClient()
                            .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                        .post<string, MyResponseModel>(url, "city=Dubai");
```