# Code executing in wrong order and it isn't async (I think...)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code below. Why does console.log("done:) execute before the loop finishes? I get it that "request" is async but my console.log is inside the callback function. The callback function is synchronous (as far as I can see) and starts going through the loop, then when the loop finishes it should execute my console.log("done"). But it doesn't. It executes it before (or right after the first iteration of the loop). Is the loop async too? It's the only way I could explain what is happening.

```
const request = require('request');

var item_urls;
var options = {
    json: true
  };
var test = [] ;


function updateDB (){
    var url = "https://api.warframe.market/v1/items";


    request(url, options, (error, res, body) =>{
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error)
          };

          if (!error && res.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log("executing cb1");
            item_urls = body.payload.items;
            var primes = item_urls.filter(item => item.item_name.includes("Strun Wraith Set"));
            for (item in primes) // Loop through items, then and add to recipelist. This is to make it the same name as the URL attribute.
            {
                let url = `https://api.warframe.market/v1/items/${primes[item].url_name}`;
               // console.log (url);
                request(url, options, (error, res, body) =>{
                    if (error) {
                        return console.log(error)
                      };

                      if (!error && res.statusCode == 200) {

                          console.log(`Getting item ${url}`);
                          test.push(body.payload.item);
                      }
                    });

            };  
            console.log ("done");          


          };
    });
}
updateDB ();
```

Comment: You caught that console.log should be inside the callback for the first request. But inside the loop you are making requests which are also async. You'd need to track that all the requests inside the loop had finished in order to know that it was done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` loop is **NOT** asynchronous and the `console.log("done")` does indeed run after the loop. However you are making an asynchronous request within the `for` loop which is why you're seeing the inner request callback's `console.log` afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that an sync operation INSIDE a sync operation could exit the parent operation. I was aware that request is async but I thought it would only "non-block" within it's parent loop. That doesn't sound natural; you even say yourself that the for loop is synchronous so you wouldn't expect ANYTHING to exit the loop until to completes. Thanks

Comment: Any chance you could show me how amend it then to display it when the loop finishes?

Comment: Depends on the version of node that you're on. You can use a lib like [sync-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-request) or wrap each request with a `Promise` and use the `async` `await` pattern.

Comment: `async`/`await` was introduced in nodejs 7.6, if you're on this version or higher then see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53555629/2832532) for an example of this pattern.

Comment: ok, i had a feeling I had to do it that way. Just wanted to double check though as I'm a bit of noob to node.js. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
request(url, options, (error, res, body) => { ... })
```

Even without knowing anything about `request`, you can tell this is an asynchronous function invocation: instead of returning a result, it accepts a function to run on said result.

Synchronous invocation would have looked like this:

```
let [error, res, body] = request(url, options);
```